# Inline statement keypairvalues

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following HtmlLink:

```
HtmlLink htmlLink = new HtmlLink(); 
htmlLink.Attributes.Add("href", "/style/" + category + ".css"); 
htmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css"); 
htmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
```

Im trying to write it in a one line statement, but I dont know the right syntax to write a statement like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Doing:

```
HtmlLink htmlLink = new HtmlLink() { ???? };
```

Can someone satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: I don't think this will work because the Attributes property is readonly so you cannot use the new object initialization with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell it can't be done. You could always write an extension method:

```
public static void AddAttributes(this HtmlLink thisLink, IDictionary<string, string> attributes)
{
  foreach(var attribute in attributes.Keys)
  {
    thisLink.Attributes.Add(attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var link = new HtmlLink();
link.AddAttributes(new Dictionary<string,string>{{"Key1","Value1"},{"Key2","Value2"}};
```

Not sure this has a great advantage over multiple adds though. Another option is to write a helper method somewhere that accepts a dictionary and spits out an HtmlLink with its attributes set.

Comment: I have no concrete uses for it, but I was curious about. Thank you.